# IntelliJ gradle add module dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Using IntelliJ 2016.2.
Using Gradle 2.14.1

I have 2 projects, each with their own build.gradle files and separate directory structures:

```
myLib (meant to be jarred and used by others)
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  - src/main/java/...

sandbox (spring boot web app)
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
  - src/main/java/...
  - src/main/resources/...
```

Hopefully, you get the picture. Within IntelliJ, I have the following module structure, at the same level (no subprojects):

```
- myLib
- sandbox
```

Simple request ... I want to use `myLib` within the `sandbox` app. I want both modules in the same project in order to develop both.

I've tried adding a module dependency to `sandbox` for `myLib` within IntelliJ. No dice. I've tried adding a jar reference, no dice.

I believe I need to add a dependency in the build.gradle file but cannot figure out how. I've tried `compile files '<path to myLib.jar>'`, etc. No dice.

Comment: Do you have a top-level `bulid.gradle` and `settings.gradle` outside of those two modules?

Comment: No, I do not. Separate dir structures at the same level.

Comment: I realize I could create the 'lib' dir in 'sandbox' and copy the 'myLib' jar file over every time I rebuilt and jarred 'myLib', but I'm looking for a better solution. Thought IntelliJ and/or Gradle would put this together for me.

Comment: It's weird, I've noticed when I tell idea to add a dependency on the given module, it only does that in the .idea files and not somewhere else.

Comment: Similarly, if I add a dependency within IntelliJ IDE project settings, then it resolves the errors within the IDE editor; however, I cannot build because no change is made by IntelliJ to the build.gradle and settings.gradle files.  So I manually added the dependency following the solution below.  That is in the outer settings file I added   "include ':myLib'"  and in the build file I added "compile project( ':myLib')".  Apparently the colon is a delimiter used by gradle to denote the sub-projects hierarchy

Comment: If you want more automation in the process (maybe that's what you were trying to do), try [Automating synchronization when developping several libraries and projects at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875198/automating-synchronization-when-developping-several-libraries-and-projects-at-th).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

#### Local Modules

This is a pattern followed by most Gradle projects where there is a library, then a sample app that uses that library - [ref Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:adding_subprojects)

```
 - app/
    - build.gradle
    - src/main/java  # where your main class would be 
 - library/
    - build.gradle
    - src/main/java  # dependencies of the app module 
 - settings.gradle
 - build.gradle
```

In that top-level `settings.gradle` you have

```
include ':library', ':app'
```

And in the `app/build.gradle`, you compile that included project

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Basically, the top-level `build.gradle`, is a wrapper for all common configs of the sub projects and variables. For example, it's most commonly used for a `repositories { }` section for Maven urls, for example. Full details on that are at [Gradle - Multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

#### Remotes Modules

The above is fine for working locally, but let's say you wanted to share your repo with many other developers without making them download extra source code. Then your would publish the other libraries to a remote server.

This is what you already doing when you add these lines to your project

```
implementation("org:artifact:version")
```

If your projects are **public on GitHub**, use a service like [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/). You can also setup an account on Bintray OSS or Maven Central to have your libraries be available like most others.

If your projects are **private within your company**, you will need some Maven type server, whether that is a generic web server, or Nexus or Artifactory, you can [add that with an addition to the repositories block.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html)

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://some.maven.site/" }
}
```

Then add the `compile` or `implementation` sources, as normal

Comment: This sounds reasonable and exactly what I want to do, however, I'm having some trouble getting things worked out with IntelliJ. Thanks, I'll mark this as the solution. Just curious, what IDE do you usually use?

Comment: I use Intellij IDEA. I've only ever created one Gradle Java project, though

Comment: You still have to manually perform the steps to update the library files when there is a change, for each project, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you release a new version of a library, or edit the version of a local one, you need to update the line of the dependency block, yes. Or you just use a `:+`, which is not recommended

Comment: @cricket_007: please do not use "not recommended" as a reason to not provide a solution. This ":+" may be exactly what I've been looking for. Can you elaborate in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875198/automating-synchronization-when-developping-several-libraries-and-projects-at-th) thread perchance? Or is my solution there already the proper one?

Comment: `Could not find method include() for arguments [../My-Library-Name] on root project 'My-Project-Name' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @Ben make sure it's settings file, not build file, then it takes a module name, not a file location https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[])

Comment: The answer was totally unhelpful except for the link to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html . This link helps. Thank you.

Comment: Does it not work if the dependency class does not have a main method?

Comment: @paradocslover Libraries are modules too, so yes

Comment: Yes, it does not work OR yes, it works? The thing is I tried this yesterday with one of my projects and it didn't work

Comment: @paradoc It works. My answer is direct from the documentation and the shown "library" module would have no main method. Perhaps you can post a new question with your code and the issues you're having

Comment: Use
`implementation project(':library')`

instead of 

`compile project(':library')`

Answer (score 12):

Finally Gradle 3.1 has sorted out this issue. Composite builds are now supported natively. More [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).
In short add this line to sandbox settings.gradle file-

```
includeBuild '<PATH>/myLib'
```

If you can't upgrade Gradle, then the only hope for you is to publish mylib artifact to local maven repo and add mavenLocal() to sandbox/build.gradle.

Comment: Your link seems to be missing that `includeBuild` directive

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is just to keep lib folder at parent dir of project and include below line in your module build.gradle file

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: ['*.aar'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I recently just had the same problem, and here is my solution:

Assuming this file tree:

```
.
|- app
|  |- src
|  |  |- ...
|  |- build.gradle
|
|- lib
|  |- src
|  |  |- ...
|  |- build.gradle
|
|- settings.gradle
```

You can set up your gradle project as such:

- `./settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'some-project'
include 'app'
include 'lib'
```

- `./app/build.gradle`

```
// ...
dependencies {
    // depend on sibling module lib
    implementation project(':lib')
}
// ...
```

Lastly, make sure that what you are tying to import from the `lib` module is not in the base package.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is outdated in modern gradle and intellij, please refer to [darwinbaisa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40236255/2187042)

**Original answer**

Its discussed in the article https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/10/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-gradle-composite-builds-and-android-studio-2-2/

Basically you need to use composite builds. So View > Tool windows > Gradle > Right Click on the project using the library > Composite Build Configuration > Tick the library project you want to use the local version of.

Do a rebuild and then the local dependancy should be used

Comment: As of Idea 2019.1 Community Edition, there is no `Composite Build Configuration` there

Comment: @EugeneGr.Philippov Yes, in newer versions darwinbaisa's answer is the way to go