# trying to share code created in a android library module

Tags: android

Im trying to share a class (between 2 apps) created in a Android Library Module. called cTest .  When I try to declare it in my, code says it is undfined.

This is what I did:

1. created a new project called testdouble.
2. created a new app by going to new module, phone & tablet module and called it app1.  The package name was "com.example.app1"
3. created another app called app2 but change the package name to "com.example.app1", so both apps have the same package name.
4. created a new libary module by going to new moduleandroid library.  I change the package name to "com.example.app1.common and set the
   name of library to common.
5. added the 2 gradle strips labeled  build gradle(Module app1) build gradle(Module app1) I added the line build gradle(Module app1) inside
   the dependencies block.

I then created a new class in common java folder called cTest

in file MainActvy for app1 i added the line

```
cTest t;
```

got a error saying `ctest` was undefinned.

My files are as follows

App1 mainacticty

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CTest t; // says cTest does not exist
```

App2 mainacticty

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CTest t; // says cTest does not exist
```

.....

Gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile project(":common")
}
```

Comment: Add `settings.gradle` also. And your app2 and app1 activites are the same in your post.

Comment: "created another app called app2 but change the package name to "com.example.app1", so both apps have the same package name" -- that is unlikely to work well. "I then created a new class in common java folder called cTest" -- in this question, you show `cTest`, `ctest`, and `CTest`. None of those are the same, as Java is case-sensitive. If your class is named `cTest`, a reference to `CTest` will not find it.

Comment: See project setup layout here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877989/intellij-gradle-add-module-dependency/38878290#38878290  If you want to reference common package classes, you are missing an import

Comment: I thought the apps sharing the code and the library module must all have the same package name???

Comment: have you added this package as dependency to both the apps, if not this might be causing problem