# Kotlin: How to import a class from another IntelliJ module?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a simple Kotlin project in IntelliJ with two modules defined as sub-folders under the project root folder. Everything seems to be set up correctly in build settings, each module has its own folder marked as a source directory.

I can run main functions in both modules so IntelliJ is finding everything OK.

What I cannot do is reference a public class in one module in the other. I've tried every form of import statement I can think of, but the compiler always flags the class in module1 as an unresolved reference in module2.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38878290/104891) help?

Comment: I don't think that helps. I'm not building w/ gradle, just IntelliJ's own tools.

Comment: Then you need to define the dependencies between the modules, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Comment: *Whew* that was tricky. IntelliJ doesn't work quite the way the docs say, there's no "File | Convert Module Groups to Qualified Names" option. But the other bits were helpful. If you create a module group, flatten it, then define your dependencies, it all works. Thanks for the pointers!