# How to import classes from another module in Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, import, module

I am trying to write an import statement to access a scala class in another module in a java project in intellij.

I found this question which appears to be related:

[Kotlin: How to import a class from another IntelliJ module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660635/kotlin-how-to-import-a-class-from-another-intellij-module)

I've followed the steps for grouping and flattening the modules; however, I cannot find an import statement that works. I am not using a Kotlin project, so perhaps that's the difference.

I was able to get an import statement to work when I included the scala project as a jar dependency(instead of as a separate module); however, doing it that way created problems with intellij not recognizing scala-specific portions of the code. I don't know much about building Jars in intellij, so it's possible I'm not building it properly - I am used to Eclipse where a jar is just a jar and you're done.

Here is the line I am attempting to use the import statement for:

```
public class Display {
    public static Screen screen = new Screen(Resolution.FULL_SCREEN(), Screen.DEFAULT_SCALE());
}
```

Path to dependency:

```
storm.screen/src/main/scala/Screen.scala
```

Path to working class:

```
storm.core/src/output/Display.java
```

Currently every import path I've tried gives an error message of 'cannot resolve symbol'.

Edit: I've now successfully added a module dependency from a different module which is a Java project - the issue here seems to be isolated to the Scala project module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by creating an entirely new maven project, manually copying the source files from the existing modules, and following the procedures in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396411/integrating-scala-into-an-existing-project-in-java).

Oddly, as long as the scala classes are inside of a directory called 'java', they work just fine - but if the directory is renamed 'scala', the imports break.