# Gradle dependency of modules in intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, module, dependencies

I have 2 modules in an intellij project..One intellij plugin module and another one is an gradle module.
I need to call a class of the plugin module from the gradle module..I did add dependency of module by following this path: Project structure->module->Module dependency.But it is not resolved.
I have also added the below code in:

settings.gradle

```
include ':Change',':module'
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies{
  compile project (:Change)
}
```

Here 'Change' is the name of the intellij plugin module.

Every time I try to build the gradle it throws below error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':distTar'.
 Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :ChangeImpactAnalysis.
Required by:
project :
> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :ChangeImpactAnalysis: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ gradle add module dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877989/intellij-gradle-add-module-dependency)

Comment: `I did add dependency of module by following this path: Project structure->module->Module dependency.But it is not resolved.` You must not configure module's dependencies in IDE UI project structure in case of Gradle project. You should edit corresponding build.gradle and settings.gradle files. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877989/intellij-gradle-add-module-dependency

Comment: Where is the build.gradle of the Change project?